# Hide Users by user role in Worpress

Tags: user-roles

I'm trying to only show authors in my user's page.
I was hoping that user role editor could do the trick but apparently not.
Is there a way to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use wp_list_authors for list your authors in your user page. Put a look here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_authors Does it help you?

EDIT: According to our communications:

```
$users_array = array();
$users = get_users('role=author');
if(count($users) > 0){
    foreach($users as $user){
        $users_array[] = $user->ID;
    }
}
```

add $users_array instead of array(1, 3, 5) ...

Comment: I must say that I'm not sure what you want. If I'm wrong, can you enlighten me please?

Comment: Hi, I just want to show users that are "Editors" in my user's page. :)

Comment: I wanted to paste the code but it's too long..

Comment: You can use get_users( 'role=editor' ). Look here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/

Comment: Here is the code!
https://www.codepile.net/pile/OMYVOZjE

Comment: Do:

<?php
$users_editor = get_users('role=editor' );
foreach($users_editor as $editor){
echo $editor->ID;
} ?>

Comment: Can you insert that in the code I gave you? Can't understand it.. :/

Comment: Yes! Look here: https://www.codepile.net/pile/5R21JyBO

I replace your conditionnal $number variable too.

Comment: The page won't load...Broken! :/

Comment: I test witout your superfluous code for pagination. You can see the code here: https://www.codepile.net/pile/aAzYV18K and it's work good for me.

Comment: I reply to you in the chat, sorry for the delay